# MS Excel - Select Random Names From a List

Tags: excel, random

Everyone,
I have this Excel that contain data. and I want to check some of the data randomly.
Is there's a way to randomly pick Name with specific number?

Example:
In the image i attached, There are 4 people to Drawing. and i only need to check 2, so what I want is to randomly choose 2 drawing from the 4 given. is that possible? Maybe highlighted the name of the chosen or any.

[Image For Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xk8Sx.jpg)

Comment: Where do you want the randomly picked names displayed? U might need VBA for this

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. I'm not sure if I understand your question completely, but I'm assuming you're trying to select one or more names randomly. You could use something like this:

```
=index(A2:A10,randbetween(1,9))
```

This will return one element from cells A2 to A10, selected randomly.

Comment: Hi, Rahul. thank you for you're time. May problem is randomly pick name with a given number in the cell highlighted. let just say i have 100 data and i only need to check 9 of it. is there a way that in 100, 9 of them will be randomly pick by highlighted?

Comment: With or without repetition?